# How to join two arrays of html elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, push, concatenation

I`v already tried concat and push methods but it did not worked to me. Thats what i want to do :

```
var left = document.getElementById('main-left').children;
var right = document.getElementById('main-right').children;
var main = left.concat(right); 

left = [<article class=​"content">​…​</article>​, <article class=​"content">​…​     </article>​, <article class=​"content">​…​</article>​]
right = [<article class=​"content">​…​</article>​, <article class=​"content">​…​ </article>​, <article class=​"content">​…​</article>​]
```

Answer (score 2):

getElementById() never returns an array, so push and concat won't be available on 'left' and 'right' objects. you can try something like this:

```
    function logElementArray(){
    var leftArray = document.getElementById('left').children;
    var rightArray = document.getElementById('right').children;
    var mainArray=[];
    for(var i=0; i<rightArray.length; i++){
        mainArray.push(rightArray[i]);
    }
    for(var i=0; i<leftArray.length; i++){
        mainArray.push(leftArray[i]);
    }
 }
```

Your 'mainArray' will have all the elements then.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed should use concat, but like this:

```
var left = document.getElementById('main-left').children;
var right = document.getElementById('main-right').children;

left = [].slice.call(left);
var main = left.concat.apply(left, right);

// or even var main = [].concat.apply([], [[].slice.call(left), [].slice.call(right)]);
```

`left` is not an Array instance, so it doesn't have Array.prototype methods like `slice` or `concat`, so you need to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects).

Or you could of course simple use for loop and populate new array in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet for adding elements to an array and then adding the elements in the array to an element.

If this is what your trying to do using appendChild() is probably better.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var b = "";
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  b += a[i].outerHTML;
  console.log(a[i]);
}
var c = document.getElementById("main");
c.innerHTML = b;
```

```css
.test {
  border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
  height: 50px;
}
#main {
  border: 5px solid firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First see that `left` and `right` are not arrays in any sense. You have to perform `document.querySelectorAll` or `document.getElementsByClassName` to get an array and then you can apply array like methods to join them.
Most preferably use:

```
// `a` into `b`:
for (var i=a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
     b.unshift( a[i] );
}
```

Comment: It doensn't matter how you get the `NodeList`. A NodeList it a NodeList and not an array.